# How to set WindowSoftInputModeAdjust to Resize for a specific page?

Tags: maui, window-soft-input-mode

In my MAUI project, I want to set the `WindowSoftInputModeAdjust` to `Resize` on a specific page and `WindowSoftInputModeAdjust` to `Pan` on other pages since it affects my other pages UI like below.

[image]

I tried using the code below, but it didn't work.

I added the below code on the cs page where I need the resize option:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
try
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    App.Current.On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + e);
}
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
try
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    App.Current.On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + e);
}
}
```

I added the below code on the cs page where I need the pan option:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
try
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    App.Current.On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + e);
}
}
```

I set the `WindowSoftInputModeAdjust` to Pan on `MainActivity.cs`. Please provide a solution for this?

**Update**

The UI issue is happening on the home page only after the comment page keyboard open after the editor tap. If I view the comment page and without opening keyboard, no UI issue in home page. When keyboard is opening that page is resizing and as a result home page is also resizing.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q60844sYKqu_Ps9Ilsw0tKM9Jt_vtUBS/view?usp=sharing) is the full explanation video.

If I am not using resize option on the inner page, the header part is not visible on the UI like below screenshot:

[image]

That issue [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C7WTVY2_9Iuxd6a9LF1eLYPXJ51T582h/view).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is an known issue: [[regression/8.0.0] [Android] WindowSoftInputModeAdjust not working anymore](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18041). You can follow up it.

And then, you can use the android native platform code to set the **WindowSoftInputModeAdjust**.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
try
{
    base.OnAppearing();
#if ANDROID 
    Platform.CurrentActivity?.Window?.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize);
#endif
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + e);
}
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
try
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
#if ANDROID 
    Platform.CurrentActivity?.Window?.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan);
#endif
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + e);
}
}
```

In addition, you can use the `Platform.CurrentActivity?.Window?.Attributes?.SoftInputMode` to get the current SoftInputMode.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256564/discussion-on-answer-by-liyun-zhang-msft-how-to-set-windowsoftinputmodeadjust); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.